# Protobuf Decode Error when reading bytes from withing Bitbucket

Tags: python, encoding, bitbucket, proto

I have a protobuf file saved as bytes on Windows.
I am reading it as follows:

```py
tlog = tlog_schema_pb2.TLog()
with open("tests/unittests/data/tlog.proto", "rb") as f:
    tlog.ParseFromString(f.read())
```

It all fine. But when I push my changes with git to Bitbucket, there I get an error:

```
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'globusdigital.tlogprocessing.TLog'
```

I cannot understand what can it be. What can change when I push to Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem was in pre-commit.
I had trailing-whitespace check there, and it was destructing protobuf file.

To solve it, just add

```
files: '\.pyi?$'
```

at the end of `.pre-commit-config.yaml` (would be cool to exclude files, but did not understand how)